# Postgresql кортеж в цикле FOR

Tags: sql, postgresql

Мне нужно внутри функции итерироваться по парам значений, записанных в таблице. Я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:

```
  FOR ids IN SELECT old_id, id FROM ids_mapping LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'id = %, old_id = %', ids.id, ids.old_id;        
  END LOOP;
```

(переменная ids определена, DECLARE ids record;), но ids принимает значения пустого кортежа из 2 элементов - (,)

В соответствии с информацией по ссылке ниже, это должно работать для Postgres 11, я работаю на 9. Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи, в чем причина ошибки?

[Iterating with tuple, Postgres 11](https://books.google.ru/books?id=St18DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=the%20tuple%20loop%20variable%20must%20be%20a%20record%20or%20tuple%20variable%20or%20a%20list%20of%20scalar%20variables&source=bl&ots=jbjgXlH9Wj&sig=ACfU3U2TsSgVIjb8PlOC2uDZa2Zl0imxAA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHrsGVkbTkAhXNAxAIHQZCBnYQ6AEwAnoECBMQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20tuple%20loop%20variable%20must%20be%20a%20record%20or%20tuple%20variable%20or%20a%20list%20of%20scalar%20variables&f=false)

Comment: "В соответствии с информацией по ссылке ниже, это **должно работать** для **Postgres 11**, **я работаю на 9**. Есть ли какие-нибудь идеи, в чем причина ошибки?" идея в том, что должно работать для 11, а вы работаете на 9

Comment: Хорошо, я, наверное, плохо сформулировал вопрос.
Как сделать аналогичный запрос на 9 постгрес?

Answer (score 1):

Получилось вот так, но если кто-то знает более изящный способ, буду рад узнать его

```
  FOR ids IN EXECUTE 'SELECT old_id, id FROM ids_mapping' LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'id = %, old_id = %', ids.id, ids.old_id;        
  END LOOP;
```